# setup.py missing __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

I've installed a personalize the python package by

```
python setup.py build; sudo python setup.py install
```

After the installation, there is no `__init__.py` file under the package, which causes the import problem, anyone has idea, why during the installation, the setup.py misses the `__init__.py` file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how does your `setup.py` looks like and how does your directory structure of the application you're trying to install looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your setup.py and make sure there is not a namespace_packages pointing to the package in question. For the explanation why this happens, take a look here:
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages